# Meteor client side collection needs to have all data populated before anything else

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to use a client side collection as a site configuration system. I insert documents representing my different pages, and the `iron-router` and navigation tabs all use them to determine what pages they are and what templates are represented by them. Each page uses a `{{> contentTemplate}}` inclusion helper to load it's relevant template.

It all works great, *when* the data has all loaded. When I restart the app on certain pages, the data hasn't loaded yet, and I receive the `Exception from Deps recompute function: Error: Expected null or template in return value from inclusion function, found: undefined` error.

Here's my javascript:

```js
StoriesArray = [
{ category: 'teaching', contentTemplate: 'teachingHome', title: 'Teaching Home'},
...
];

Stories = new Meteor.Collection(null);
StoriesArray.forEach(function (story, index) {
    story._id = index + '';
    Stories.insert(story);
});

// in main.js
Template.teachingPost.contentTemplate = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.contentTemplate);
    return Template[this.contentTemplate];
};

// in router.js
this.route('teaching', {
    layoutTemplate: 'teachingPost',
    data: function() { return Stories.findOne({contentTemplate: 'teachingHome', category: 'teaching'}); }
});
```

The console logs in the `contentTemplate` helper above log twice, the first time as this:

```
Object {} main.js?1f560c50f23d9012c6b6dd54469bb32b99aa4285:45

undefined main.js?1f560c50f23d9012c6b6dd54469bb32b99aa4285:46
```

and the second time as this:

```
Object {category: "teaching", contentTemplate: "teachingHome", title: "Teaching Home"} main.js?1f560c50f23d9012c6b6dd54469bb32b99aa4285:45

teachingHome main.js?1f560c50f23d9012c6b6dd54469bb32b99aa4285:46
```

so the router is simply trying to load this data too early.

I've tried putting the `StoriesArray` loading process into different files all over my app, including `lib`, and even tried putting it into `Meteor.startup`, but it's always the same result.

The normal `iron-router` `waitOn`/`subscription` pattern doesn't really apply here, since this is a client side collection built with `null`, that has no server representation. I don't *want* this to have server representation, because this is static content that there's no need to go to my server for.

How do I ensure this information is done before continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but per [Iron Router's docs on `waitOn`](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#controlling-subscriptions):

> Returning a subscription handle, or anything with a `ready` method from the `waitOn` function will add the handle to a wait list.

Also in general it's better to use `find` with `data`, rather than `findOne`, as `find` will return an empty cursor when the collection is empty as opposed to `findOne` returning `undefined`. So try this:

```
// in router.js
this.route('teaching', {
  layoutTemplate: 'teachingPost',
  data: function() {
    return Stories.find({contentTemplate: 'teachingHome', category: 'teaching'});
  },
  waitOn: function() {
    var handle = {};
    handle.ready = function() {
      if (Stories.find().count() !== 0)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
    return handle;
  }
});
```

And adjust your `Template.teachingPost.contentTemplate` function to work with a cursor rather than an object.

Comment: Same result :/ I added `console.log(Stories.find().count());` within the `ready` function, as well as  logs that show which outcome the `ready` function chooses, and they show `9` and `true`, both *before* the logs of `Object{}` and `undefined`. I'm very confused about why it isn't working.

Comment: Iron Router runs `waitOn()` immediately, and since the handle inside returns `false`, Iron Router should queue this route to rerun later on; and later on when the handle eventually returns `true` Iron Router should move on to rendering the route. So of course `console.log` inside the `ready` function will run several times, as Iron Router keeps checking until it's ready.

Comment: Also try using `find` instead of `findOne`. It's much better to work with cursors when rendering templates, rather than the naked objects returned by `findOne`, because `findOne` could sometimes return `undefined` which causes errors.

Comment: `findOne` works fine. I had some other things that were causing things to get jammed up. I'm accepting your answer asap!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mean to say that `findOne` couldn't work, just that you should check for `undefined` if you use it; whereas `find` doesn't have that issue (hence why I prefer it).